# Using pivot_longer and pivot_gather to tidy a dummy-filled dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, spread

Friends, hello! I have a dataframe of some 2 million employees from one industry and the firms they have worked with from 2000-2019. It looks something like this:

```
| ID |  FIRM | NAICS | Q1 | Q2 | Q3 | Q4 |
| A  |   001 |   100 |  1 |  1 |  1 |  1 |
| B  |   002 |   200 |  1 |  1 |  0 |  0 |
| B  |   003 |   100 |  0 |  0 |  1 |  1 |
```

... where NAICS is the industry code of the company where someone worked in a given quarter. For example, *Person A* stayed in the same industry all four quarters; *Person B* moved from *Industry 200* to *Industry 100* in *Q3* by moving firms.

The frame I would like to end up with looks like this:

```
| ID |  Q1 |  Q2 |  Q3 |  Q4 |
| A  | 100 | 100 | 100 | 100 |
| B  | 200 | 200 | 100 | 100 |
```

... so that I can track what industries people are coming from, and then build something akin to [this NYT animated sankey diagram](https://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2018/03/19/upshot/race-class-white-and-black-men.html).

Could you help me figure out how to get from the first to the second? My hunch is that I need to be use `dplyr::pivot_longer()` and `dplyr::pivot_wider()`, which I understand are replacing `spread()` and `gather()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's basically three steps here:

- Make it long so that each quarter is its own row
- Drop the rows where the firm was "inactive" in that quarter
- Make it wide, spreading the "quarter" variable into columns

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(
    cols = Q1:Q4,
    names_to = "quarter",
    values_to = "active"
  ) %>%
  filter(active == 1) %>%
  select(- FIRM, - active) %>%
  pivot_wider(
    names_from = quarter,
    values_from = NAICS
  )
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 5
  ID       Q1    Q2    Q3    Q4
  <fct> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1 A       100   100   100   100
2 B       200   200   100   100
```

Comment: So helpful--thanks!! And @dc37 is right; this crashes out with a larger dataframe ("# Error: vector memory exhausted (limit reached?)".

Comment: Ah OK, I don't know exactly how efficient `pivot_longer`/`wider` are with larger datasets. I would think that R should be able to deal with an 8 miilion row (2 million x 4) dataset, so maybe the pivot functions are using a lot of memory while carrying out the pivot.

Answer (score 1):

As your dataframe contains ID for 2 millions of employees, maybe a solution with `melt` and `dcast` functions from `data.table` package will be faster for you:

```r
library(data.table)
setDT(dt)
Col <- paste("Q",1:4,sep = "")
dt.m <- melt(dt, measure = list(Col), variable.name = "quarter", value.name = "value")
dt.m <- dt.m[value == 1]
dt.m[,value:= NULL]
dt.m <- dcast(dt.m, ID~quarter, value.var = "NAICS")

   ID  Q1  Q2  Q3  Q4
1:  A 100 100 100 100
2:  B 200 200 100 100
```

---

**Reproducible Data**

```r
dt <- data.frame(ID = c("A","B","B"),
                 NAICS = c(100,200,100),
                 Q1 = c(1,1,0),
                 Q2 = c(1,1,0),
                 Q3 = c(1,0,1),
                 Q4 = c(1,0,1))
```

Comment: It remove the column `value` as we don't need anymore. It is equivalent to `select(-active)` in @Marius's answer.

Comment: Thanks @dc37! I thought we had this one--but turns out I get the same overload problem here as with the dplyr option: `Error: vector memory exhausted (limit reached?)` Suggestions welcome; regardless, grateful for both your and @marius's answers.

Comment: ... hard to find a good suggestion. It will depend how big is your file... I'm not enough an expert on manipulating very heavy file. Sorry for that. Maybe if you can find a way to work on a cluster, it will makes things easier. But it is well beyond my knowledge.  Good luck